# Query listener does not work when 'Where' clause is added

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rx-swift

I have a query that provides 'feed' data to a collection view using RxSwift and RxFirebase.
This feed data now has a 'Privacy' field (possible values: "Public", "Sub", and "Private") and I need to filter out the 'Private' entities.

However when I add a 'Where' clause to do this, the listener no longer adds newly posted entities from this collection. The first call to this function always has the 'listens' bool set to true, because it wants to listen for new entities posted/deleted by a user.
I do not know why the events do not trigger the query.

Here is the current query code:

```
 func fetchGlobalFeed(limit: Int, startAfter: Timestamp?, listens: Bool) -> Observable<[Entity.Fragment]> {
     var query = db.collection(k.mCollection)
         .limit(to: limit)
         .order(by: "PublishedAt", descending: true)

    if let timestamp = startAfter {
         query = query.start(after: [timestamp])
    }

    let observable = listens ? query.rx.listen() : query.rx.getDocuments()
    return observable
          .catchErrorJustComplete()
          .map(FirestoreHelpers.dataFromQuerySnapshot)
          .map { data in
               data.compactMap {
                   try? FirestoreDecoder()
                       .decode(Entity.Fragment.self, from: $0)
               }
          }
 }
```

And changing the query to:

```
 var query = db.collection( k.mCollection ) 
               .limit( to: limit ) 
               .whereField( "Privacy", in: ["Public", "Sub"] ) // <- this causes issue with listener 
               .order( by: "PublishedAt", descending: true )
```

Maybe an explanation of how listeners work and any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks.

```
 RxFirebase version: 0.3.8
```

*Edit:
I don't have enough Rep to post pictures which is weird because I used to be able to. (says it requires 10 rep pts)

Here is the debug output:

> 2020-09-10 11:37:03.101: MagmaFirestoreProvider.swift:165
> (fetchGlobalFeed(limit:startAfter:listens:)) -> subscribed
>
> 2020-09-10 11:37:03.324: MagmaFirestoreProvider.swift:165
> (fetchGlobalFeed(limit:startAfter:listens:)) -> Event
> next([Entity.Fragment(ref: <FIRDocumentReference: 0x60000109ef40>,
> publisher: Optional(UserEntity.Fragment(ref: <FIRDocumentReference:
> 0x60000109ee80>, username: "Art_Collective", name: nil .........
> privacy: Optional(magma.MagmaMagPrivacy.Public))])
>
> 2020-09-10 11:37:03.458: MagmaFirestoreProvider.swift:165
> (fetchGlobalFeed(limit:startAfter:listens:)) -> Event completed
>
> 2020-09-10 11:37:03.458: MagmaFirestoreProvider.swift:165
> (fetchGlobalFeed(limit:startAfter:listens:)) -> isDisposed

When a new item is posted to the feed with a privacy of "Sub", the item does not appear and there is zero debug output.
I have to refresh the collection view to get the above output and the new item in the feed.

I assume that's because the observable is being disposed?

Comment: If the completion handler is not called, it's likely there are no documents matching your condition. Can you show a screenshot of a document you'd expect to be returned by the query? In addition: your query likely needs a custom multi-field index, so check the logging output of your app for relevant errors, or check for errors in the callback (as far as I can see, you're now ignoring them).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I put the debug() call on the observable and no errors seem to be thrown.

Comment: That function with the .whereField clause will require an index to work. Did you create that in the firebase console? Also, you're limiting your query with several factors; limit, timestamp. Did you double check the data you're attempting to return meets that criteria?

Comment: Okay, the index solution seems to be the consensus of how to get it to work, I will give that a try. @Jay yes, I know the data matches the criteria. The limit is because we have pagination, grabbing 20 items at a time, and the timestamp is so we paginate items in chronological order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments above, I created a composite index for the query in the Firebase console.

I will note that it was important to have the index structure a certain way.
I tried creating an index with the following settings:

> Collection ID : 'mags'
>
> - Field 1: 'PublishedAt' : 'Descending'
> - Field 2: 'Privacy' : 'Descending'
>
> (note: firebase docs say to use either 'Ascending' or 'Descending'
> when you're using the 'in' clause even if you're not ordering on this
> field, it will not affect the equality of the query results)

This index did not work for some reason, I'm not sure why...

However, I realized other indexes created by a dev before me were mechanically similar but structured differently. So I mirrored that with the following:

> Collection ID : 'mags'
>
> - Field 1: 'Privacy' : 'Ascending'
> - Field 2: 'PublishedAt' : 'Descending'

And it worked!